# How do I use a fluent wait command effectively in webdriver?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, webdriver

I have a scenario where I want to click on a hyperlink for a contract number on a page to open another window. The issue I originally had is that this contract number takes a few seconds before it becomes visible on the page. Therefore, I thought I’d make use of a fluent wait to poll a search on the element every few seconds until it became visible (I wanted to avoid using Thread.Sleep). However, I’m having issues getting this to work. I’ve detailed below what I’ve done

1) See below for a screenshot of the contract I am trying to click on (254052). This is the contract which takes a few seconds before it appears on the page
[image: screenshot]

The associated HTML for this is below:

```
<div id="tabular-breakdown" class="tablesorter" style="display: block;">
<table class="tablesorterReport" data-currentpage="0" data-totalcount="696" data-totalpages="35">
<thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a class="" target="_blank" href="/DibsAndrew/CreditControl/AgreementDetail.aspx?contractno=254052">254052</a>
```

2) So, what I am trying to achieve is to wait for a contract number to be displayed on the list, after which I will click on it. I’ve written the code for a fluentWait, as below:

```
    public static void fluentWaitOnContractSelect(InternetExplorerDriver driver)
{
    FluentWait<InternetExplorerDriver> wait = new FluentWait<InternetExplorerDriver>(driver);
    wait.withTimeout(8000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.pollingEvery(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
    wait.ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class);

    WebElement contractSelect = wait.until(new Function<InternetExplorerDriver, WebElement>(){

        public WebElement apply(InternetExplorerDriver driver) {
            WebElement contract = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tabular-breakdown']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a"));
            String value = contract.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            if(value.contains("_blank"))
            {
                contract.click();
                return contract;            
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Value is " + value);
                return null;
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Webelement value is " + contractSelect.getTagName());

}
```

3) However, when I run the test I get an error in the console, as follows:

```
“exception in thread “main” org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 8 seconds     waiting for genericControls.waitCommands$1@1b68b9a4
Build info: version: ‘2.43.1’, revision: ‘5163bce’, time: ‘2014-09-10 16:27:58′
System info: host: ‘MBD0150′, ip: ‘192.168.55.49’, os.name: ‘Windows 8.1′, os.arch: ‘amd64′,   os.version: ‘6.3’, java.version: ‘1.8.0_25′
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.timeoutException(FluentWait.java:259)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:228)
at genericControls.waitCommands.fluentWaitOnContractSelect(waitCommands.java:24)
at   genericControls.contractFunctions.openCloseContractForReportWithBarChart(contractFunctions.java:41)
at Reports.collections.breachReportCompletedSelectContract(collections.java:55)
at Reports.programMain.main(programMain.java:117)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer valid     (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 57 milliseconds
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Session ID: e9003b03-0004-4846-a0b9-6991cadac9b0
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:268)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getAttribute(RemoteWebElement.java:123)
at genericControls.waitCommands$1.apply(waitCommands.java:28)
at genericControls.waitCommands$1.apply(waitCommands.java:1)
at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:208)”
```

Does anyone have any ideas on where I might be going wrong?

Many thanks

**'eclipse-10/12/14'**
[image]

Comment: So does the test fail intermittently? Maybe be 8 seconds is not long enough of a wait for the element to be on the page. Also try removing the ignore NoSuchElementException on the wait just to make sure your selectors are working correctly.

Comment: Hi Shri, it fails every time I run the test. When I run the test it does find the contract as I get a series of 'Value is...', but then it times out with an error in the code highlighted in '2' above. at the below line of code                                               WebElement contractSelect = wait.until(new Function<InternetExplorerDriver, WebElement>                     Screenshot is attached below of Eclipse, but I understand it might not be easy to read all of it. The title is 'eclipse-10/12/14'

Comment: I've managed to attach a link for the code snippet, it's at            http://imgur.com/pvR7xHP

Comment: Change `String value = contract.getAttribute("innerHTML");` to `String value = contract.getAttribute("target");`. Note that your XPath is already selecting the anchor element, getting the `innerHTML` attribute for the anchor link will return only the text of the link.

Comment: It should be noted that WebDriverWait class ALREADY extends FluentWait and so there is not really a reason you would need to use FluentWait class directly.  WebDriverWait inherits the fluent like syntax.

Comment: Thank you, djangofan. Once I get this working I will bear what you said in mind

Comment: Hi Shri, I've made the change advised by yourself, and now get the error as highlighted here.......http://imgur.com/aG1CsS3              You might see that one of the errors is with a method in another class, which I have attached details of, too, here.....http://imgur.com/auTk7KY     I am calling my wait method separately as I wanted to create a method within a generic class that could be re-used elsewhere as there is similar functionality on the application I am creating tests on

Comment: Is it intentional that you click on the element within the wait setup? Ideally the click should happen after the element is returned from the wait method.

Comment: Hi Shri, sorry, that click may be when I was trying some different things to get this working. I'm assuming you mean the 'contract.click()'?

Comment: Yes, contract.click() within the wait method.

Comment: I can remove that Shri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the `innerHTML` of the `a` element. You should be testing against the `outerHTML` instead. The `innerHTML` value will *never* contain the attributes and thus will *never* contain the `_blank` value you are testing for. (Well, unless you can have a contract named `_blank`, which does not appear likely.) Let's take an example:

```
<a class="" target="_blank" href="/DibsAndrew/CreditControl/AgreementDetail.aspx?contractno=254052">254052</a>
```

The `innerHTML` of the above is `254052` because the `innerHTML` covers only what is inside the element. The `outerHTML` is the entire string above because the `outerHTML` covers the *element itself* plus its contents.

Ok, so what I suggested above would take care of the immediate problem. However, **I would strongly suggest changing your test to something better than matching a string in the HTML**. For instance, if the `a` element is added in its parent cell only after the contract is loaded, you should test for the presence of the `a` element in the cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot Louis, for the descriptive answer. That has certainly made things a lot clearer for me